# @Transactional isolation level seems to be not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-transactions, isolation-level

i have some question about @Transactional, a.k.a spring-tx.

In code like this.

```java
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public TestObject testTransaction(Long id, String name, String content) {
    //This is find
    TestObject testObject = testObjectRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);

    if (testObject != null) {
        System.out.println(testObject.getId() + "/"
                + testObject.getName() + "/"
                + testObject.getContent());
    }

    // update something
    testObject.changeContent(name, content);
    slowQuery();
    //delay for late
    return testObject;
}
```

If i use postman to request something like this.

first request is `http://localhost:8080/spring/test/transaction?id=1&name=123&content=123`
second request is `http://localhost:8080/spring/test/transaction?id=1&name=456&content=456`

Then I guess, first request is hanging on transaction, then second request must be reject from Spring-tx because of first request transaction's isolation level is `SERIALIZABLE`, and transaction work is not complete.

But result of two request is

```json
{
  "name":"456",
  "content":"456"
}
```

Is anyone know about transactional isolation I use mysql with docker, and spring-data-jpa also.

Comment: If you run the same queries, in the same order in a database client (psql, mysql, etc), do you get any errors? I have the feeling you might be missing something about how the actual database engine works with transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use @Transactional annotation then to ensure there are commits taken place in db use one more annotation as @EnableTransactionManagement also include the below code

```
connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
```

For more details regarding the same follow this [link](https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-transaction-management-transactional-in-depth)